# How can a library masterpage display report specific text?

Tags: birt

My reports are linked to a masterpage in a library file.  I want the masterpage to display the report name, but the report name will be different for each report.  How can the report communicate the report name to the library's masterpage?

Answer (score 1):

Use resource files.  Here's how:

1. Create and link a resource file to the report.  See the BIRT documentation [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Internationalization).  For example, if you have a report called Products_Report.rptdesign, and your application localization is US English, then your resource file should be called Products_Report_en_US.properties.
2. Create an entry in the resource file for the report name.  For example, report_name=Products Report.  You'll want the key to be the same for every report.
3. Access the resource from the library's masterpage.  For example, you could add a Dynamic Text element with this expression: reportContext.getMessage("report_name", reportContext.getLocale());

Answer (score 0):

Use global constants.  Here's how:

1. In the BIRT report designer's Outline pane select the rptdesign element.
2. Click the Script tab.
3. Create a constant.  For example: var REPORT_NAME = "Products Report";
4. Save
5. Access the constant from the library's masterpage.  For example, you could add a Dynamic Text element with the expression: REPORT_NAME;

This is a bit easier than using resources file - but with the resources file you get the ability to display a different report name to users depending on their language.